# Does SSMS support stored procedure parameter name completion?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

As shown in below image, I typed part of a stored procedure parameter name and pressed <kbd>ctrl+shift+space</kbd>, SSMS pops up the parameter info.
[image]

Is it possible to let SSMS complete the parameter name for me? I tried but can't make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can. SSMS Intellisense is pretty basic, so many people use 3rd party solutions to get around that.

But you can open the *Object Explorer* and find the Procedure in the `Database\Programmability\Stored Procedures` path and then drag & drop the *Parameters* folder to your query window.

[image]